# How to change a variable when a button has been clicked in JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

I want change a variable when I click a button in JavaFX. But when I try to use the variable from the program it says

> local variables referenced from inside a lambda must be final or effectively final.

I *can't make it final* though because I need to change it so I can use it. My code looks like this

```
Button next = new Button();
    next.setText("next");
    next.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        currentLine++;
});
```

what can i do to get around this?

Comment: you could make the variable a field

Comment: what is a field? how do i do that?

Comment: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/fields.html

Answer (score 1):

**Concept**

All the local variables used inside `annonymous inner classes` should be `final or effectively final` i.e. there state cannot change once defined.

**Reason**

The reason inner classes cannot reference `non final` local variables is because the local class instance can remain in memory even after the method returns and can change the value of the variable used causing `synchronization` issues.

**How do you overcome this ??**

1 - Declare a method which does the job for you and call it inside the action handler.

```
public void incrementCurrentLine() {
    currentLine++;
}
```

later call it:

```
next.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
    incrementCurrentLine();
});
```

2 - Declare `currentLine` as [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html). Then use its  [`incrementAndGet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#incrementAndGet--) to increment the value.

AtomicInteger currentLine = new AtomicInteger(0);

later, you can use:

```
next.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
    currentLine.incrementAndGet(); // will return the incremented value
});
```

3 - You can also declare a custom class, have methods declared in it and use them.

Answer (score 1):

There are various solutions to your problem. In addition to ItachiUchiha's post, simply declare the variable as class member like this:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    int counter = 0;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            HBox root = new HBox();
            Button button = new Button ("Increase");
            button.setOnAction(e -> {
                counter++;
                System.out.println("counter: " + counter);
            });

            root.getChildren().add( button);
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```