# Changing variables on button clicks - or in events in general

Tags: java, javafx

**Introduction to the problem**
It seams impossible to change a Veriable in a event (like so for example `button.setOnAction(e -> { x = x+2});`) and I can see why, but what if that's exactly what I need? It's actually not the first time that I needed to do that, but last time I got around it by saving the changed property directly to a file.
This time I used a really tricky trick to create a 'fake variable' by using the text in an invisibe TextField as my veriable. It works, that's not the problem, but I'd like to have a more 'elegant' salution :D

**Friuts of my research**
The only two salutions I could find were to either declare a Variable as a class member (which I don't want to do seeing that I already have six of them and don't want to tripple that amount) or to use seperate classes. (I found that here: [How to change a variable when a button has been clicked in JavaFx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29691201/how-to-change-a-variable-when-a-button-has-been-clicked-in-javafx) )

**The programm**
Here is the code of my popup window (I'll spare you of the rest of my stupid programm ^^ ), I'll explain what it does after the codebox. (Note that `props` is a properties object and one of the mentioned class members as well as `propPath` (meaning I declared it at the very top of the programm so that it can be accessed from every function)):

```
private void createNewBuff() throws Exception {
    Stage popupStage = new Stage(StageStyle.UTILITY);
    popupStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    popupStage.setTitle("Creating a new Buff");
    popupStage.setMinWidth(400);
    popupStage.setMinHeight(300);

    GridPane layoutGP = new GridPane();
    layoutGP.getColumnConstraints().addAll(
            new ColumnConstraints(200),     //TextField column    col 0
            new ColumnConstraints(10),      //Gab column         col 1
            new ColumnConstraints(60),      //tf manips column    col 2
            new ColumnConstraints(30),      //Gab column         col 3
            new ColumnConstraints(80));     //Main buttons col    col 4

    TextField tfName = new TextField("Unknown Buff");
    tfName.setPromptText("Name of the Buff, e.g. \"Unknown Buff\"");
    Label lblName = new Label("Name");
    layoutGP.add(tfName, 0, 0);
    layoutGP.add(lblName, 2, 0);
    TextField varTF = new TextField();

    TextField tfEffect = new TextField();
    tfEffect.setPromptText("Effect of the Buff, e.g. \"+10 LP\"");
    Button btnAdd = new Button("Add");
        btnAdd.setOnAction(e -> {
            String input = tfEffect.getText();
            String[] comps = input.split(" ");  //components
            if (Array.getLength(comps) == 2) {
                if (input.contains("+")) {
                    varTF.setText(varTF.getText() + input + ";");
                    layoutGP.add(new Label(input), 0, 1 + Array.getLength(varTF.getText().split(";")));
                } else if (input.contains("-")) {
                    varTF.setText(varTF.getText() + input + ";");
                    layoutGP.add(new Label(input), 0, 1 + Array.getLength(varTF.getText().split(";")));
                }
            }
        });
    layoutGP.add(tfEffect, 0, 1);
    layoutGP.add(btnAdd, 2, 1);


    Button btnDone = new Button("Done");
        btnDone.setOnAction(e -> {
            int buffNumber = 1;
            while (props.containsKey("Buff-" + buffNumber + "-name"))
                buffNumber++;
            props.setProperty("Buff-" + buffNumber + "-name", tfName.getText());
            props.setProperty("Buff-" + buffNumber + "-effect", varTF.getText());
            try {
                FileOutputStream streamOut = new FileOutputStream(propPath);
                props.store(streamOut, null);
                streamOut.close();
                popupStage.close();
            }catch (IOException someE){/*something meaningful*/}
        });
        btnDone.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    Button btnCancel = new Button("Cancel");
        btnCancel.setOnAction(e -> popupStage.close());
        btnCancel.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    layoutGP.add(btnDone, 4, 0);
    layoutGP.add(btnCancel, 4, 1);

    layoutGP.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
    Scene popupScene = new Scene(layoutGP);
    popupStage.setScene(popupScene);
    popupStage.showAndWait();
}
```

I wanted to post a picture there of how it looks once you start it and another of how it looks after you used it, but my reputation is still to low ^^
Therefor I'll provide the links to the pictures: Befor something was done https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2Ruq.png After it's used https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mCt8.png

**What the programm does**
It's pretty strait forward actually: my main programm is a character sheet and with that popup you can add a buff to it (later I'll make it so that the effects of the buff get calculated into the values of the sheed, but one step at a time ^^ ). You can set the name of the buff you want to create ("Unknown Buff" is the standart in case you forgett to set one) and then you can simply add defferent effects by writing tem into the TextField and then pressing the 'Add' button. They will list themself top to bottom in the free space. They will also, behind the scenes, save themself as one large string into a hidden TextField to make figuring out in which line each individual Effect has to be displayed and to save it to the properties file afterwards. (and that salution with the undisplayed textfield is exactly the trick I want to remove and turn into a more 'elegant' salution)

**Detailed explanaition of the code**
At first the Stage is created. Then the layout is made in form of a gridpane und the column sizes are set (every second column is for spacing reasons). After that I'm creating the line for the name (the label and the textfield) and also my tricky textfield that's used as a String variable. Now I'm creating the effect textfield and add button, as well as the event for the button: at first it turns the input from the textfield into a easier to read name and splits it into it's components (at first I used `tfEffect.getText()` and `tfEffect.getText().split(" ")` inside the code below, but that was really messy) now I have if statements to verify it and make sure that the Effect is in the right format (that format beeing the amount a certain stat is raised or lowerd, consisting of either a plus or a minus symbol at the beginning and a number after that; followed by a space and then the index of the stat (I haven't been able to implement verifying if the typed thing actually is a valid stat, maybe that'll be content of a future question ;D )). After verifying the programm it adds the effect below all the others. If you're done and happy with you're buff you can click the Done button, it will first look up how many Buffs already exist, then assign the new on a number and save it all to the properties file. The cancel button with of course just cancel it and at the bottom I'm setting the scene and calling the stage.

**What I'm hoping for with this question**
Now I think you have a pretty clear idea of what I need to do and why I couldn't find a better salution then using a hidden TextField as a variable and I hope it's because I'm a beginner and not because there actually is no better way of doing it ^^
Also if you actually read all of this you may found one or two things I can improve besides that, but that would be the special bonus ;D

Comment: You can get around it by having a class to hold your state, e.g. `class State { int x; }`, and an instance of that: `State state = new State();`. Then, in your lambda: `e -> state.x = state.x + 2`. The reason that works is that the value of the reference to `state` is passed to the lambda, not the value of `state.x`.

Comment: @Andy that's an Idea, thank you! I'll have a look if I'll use it! In the end I would have a seperate class with some dozens of variables, but at least it works :D
The question would be if that is all that more elegant, but I'd say it is - at least a bit ^^

Comment: Having a class (or classes) representing all the state and referring to it is probably desirable: it's called a "Model" in UI design. If you've heard of "MVC" or "MVP", the model is the "M" in those design patterns.

Comment: @James Wow that's interessting (I quickly googled it ^^ ), thanks!

Comment: @AndyTurner By the way, would you want to post your comment as an answer? It's exactly what I did (if I recall correctly) and I can't mark a comment as an accepted answer (obviously)